# Error with $_FILES["file"]["type"] for flv files

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

i am having trouble checking the file type of flv files with php. Here's my code

```
if($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-flv")
{ echo "true"; }
 else{ echo "false"; }
```

But my problem is that its getting into the else statements when i upload a flv... I'm unable to figure out the problem.. Please help..

EDITED->
Having the same problem for

```
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
```

as well.. while it works fine for images..

Comment: What does it say if you do `echo $_FILES['file']['type']`?

Comment: if you print this `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` what is output?

Comment: Dump the array and see what the actual value being set is? Basic debugging.

Comment: no errors @griffin.. it just jumps to the else statements.

Comment: i tried printing it "video/x-flv".. this was the output..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. Can you put up the complete code?

Comment: Have you checked what value 'type' contains? If you want to check for only the keyword flv you could use `strpos()`.

Comment: @mob if($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-flv"){ echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }

Comment: Can you post the output of `print_r( $_FILES["file"] );` please?

Comment: if i try to upload without the if condition it works fine..

Comment: Can you check the type using `gettype()`?

Comment: If you dont post the whole code, we can't help you. Anyway, be warned that this mime type is not checked on the PHP side - it's a value send by the browser (and can be altered!)

Comment: he will get "application/octet-stream" this is generic. Allowing app/octet wud be a bad idea.

Comment: @daiscog this was the output - Array ( [name] => attachment1.flv [type] => video/x-flv [tmp_name] => C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php2A4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 567612 )

Comment: i did not use a huge code to test the errors.. i just tried echo true and echo false in the else statements

Comment: The strings you've posted are equal.  This should work.  Are you sure that your code matches the above precisely?  Check for any other subtle bugs/misspellings in the original code.  Also, as mentioned below, you really shouldn't be relying on this value to determine the file-type of the uploaded file as it is set by the client and not checked at the server.  Use the [fileinfo extension](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) instead.

Comment: @daiscog YES.. I just pasted the code in my file...

Comment: the extension method is working fine.. But i feel that's not the best method to go.. I will keep it as an alternative in case i fail to debug this

Answer (score 2):

Use `finfo_file();`

Try

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
if (finfo_file($finfo, $filename) == "video/x-flv" ){}
```

Probably the file itself is not a valid FLV file.

Edited.

Comment: This function is deprecated and uses `magic.mime` so the output can be different from server to server.

Comment: That's better :) But it depends on PECL/PHP>=5.3.0. But if possible, it's better than check file extension..

Comment: @dresende Yeah but its worth a shot >:(.

Comment: getting errors with the code.. to be honest i'm not familiar with finfo.. i just replaced my condition with this.. Call to undefined function finfo_open()

Comment: @ravz Please can you post your full code? From the form to this. Chances are your FLV file is not even valid.

Comment: <form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="do/do_upload.php">    <input type="file" name="file"/>     <input type="submit"/>     </form>

Comment: `Call to undefined function finfo_open` means you don't have finfo installed (which means you have PHP < 5.3.0). You have to install it using PHP PECL.

Answer (score 1):

**1st**: Are you sure `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` is zero? If not, check [Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Usually the most common error is not to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `form` tag of your upload page.

**2nd**: Never trust `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`. This is given by the browser. You might want to check the filename extension.

```
if (strtoupper(substr($_FILES["file"]["name"], -4)) == ".FLV") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Testing file extension is a bad idea.  What stops the user setting it manually before uploading the file?  What about cases where the file _is_ valid but doesn't have the extension you expect?

Comment: @daiscog: (did not down-voted) we're talking about accuracy. mime types are all but standard. at least extensions are the same (of course you can remove them on non-windows and still open them correctly). `finfo()` is not always available as you can see on the comments of the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the filename extension is just as insecure as trusting `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` - they are BOTH set at the client side.  The only reliable solution is to use [fileinfo](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) or [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions to get the type of the files.